# Hash function for or equality

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, equality

I'm working on a program that checks for incomplete data.

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.names = {name} if pd.notna(name) else set()
        self.phones = {parsed_phone} if (parsed_phone := _parse_phone(phone)) else set()
        self.emails = {parsed_email} if (parsed_email := _parse_email(email)) else set()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (other.names & self.names) + (other.phones & self.phones) + (other.emails & self.emails) >= 1
```

As you can see, 2 contacts are equal if at least 1 of the data points (names, phones, emails) match.
Now I want to make a hash function with the same functionality as the equality function.

For example:

```
a := Contact("James Smith", "+xx xxx xx xx xx", "james.smith@email.com") == b := Contact("James Smit", "+xx xxx xx yx xx", "james.smith@email.com")
=> hash(a) == hash(b)
```

and

```
a := Contact("James Smith", "+xx xxx xx xx xx", "james.smith@email.com") == b := Contact("Jane Doe", "+zz zzz zz zz zz", "jane.doe@email.com")
=> hash(a) != hash(b)
```

What should the hash function look like?

Comment: This is not a valid equivalence relation, and trying to use these objects in a hash table makes no sense in the first place.

Comment: @KellyBundy definitely a valid hash function, even with OP's broken non-equivalence equality. But as it turns things into linear lookups, that is the equivalent of saying "don't use hashing for this".

Comment: So what is the right solution for this kind of lookup? I'd say assign unique IDs to contacts and store them by ID. Then make three separate hashtables `name->id`, `phone->id`, `email->id` and do lookups by each part.

Comment: "`a := Contact("James Smith", "+xx xxx xx xx xx", "james.smith@email.com") == b := Contact("Jane Doe", "+zz zzz zz zz zz", "jane.doe@email.com")`" - Shouldn't that be `!=`?

Answer (score 0):

If you start with three contacts `a = Contact("J", "a", "b")`, `b = Contact("J", "c", "d")` and `c = Contact("L", "c", "e")` that means `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c`. That is doable with `__eq__`.

Based on that the `hash(a) = X` which means also that `hash(b) = X` to satisfy `a == b` which also means `hash(c) = X` to satisfy `b == c`. But the result of this that `hash(a) == hash(c)`. Note that this is unrelated to any actual implementation of `hash`, whatever logic you implement within `hash` cannot satisfy your requirement.

Comment: *"But the result of this that hash(a) == hash(c)"* - And?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. They shouldn't ask for that. Since it's perfectly allowed to have unequal values having the same hash value.

Comment: I.e., I thought they were simply asking for a valid hash function. That is, equal values must have equal hashes.